# How to copy and paste code into Visual Studio watch window without indent?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When I paste or drag and drop a long LINQ expression that takes multiple lines into visual studio watch window I need to delete indents to get the result. Is there some workarounds?

Comment: Is this a known issue? If not have you created a bug report?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> after pasting?

Comment: Tried, but seems that this shortcuts doesn.t work into watch window.